# Select input filled with SQL from database

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu, html-select

I want to fill a drop down with information I am getting from MySQL database.
I make a query and want to use the while loop to echo out the input field.

What I have right now:

I see a single option selection for the drop down with no data in it.

What I want:

Information in the option selection.

```
<dt><label for="image">Bild</label></dt>
<select id="image" name="ak_image" value="<?php echo $ak_image; ?>">
<?php 
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT bi_pfad, bi_name FROM tbl_bilder "); 
  $options = ""; 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $bi_name = $row["bi_name"];
    $bi_pfad = $row["bi_pfad"];
    $options .= "<option value=\"$bi_pfad\">".$bi_name."</option>\n";
  } 
  echo $options; 
  echo "</select>\n";
?>
```

Comment: First of all.. your <select> tag with value attributes has no meaning. The <select> element does not have a value attribute so that is ignored. So, you have a single selection <select> and none of its <option> elements have the selected attribute, that means that the first <option> is taken as the default selection...

Comment: Have you checked the table you are querying to make sure there is data in it?

Comment: @Thomas Yes. I put the same query in phpmyadmin and i got all the information.

Comment: Are you checking for errors from `mysql_query`?

Comment: Do you see the options if you look do `View Source` in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Since you've verified through phpmyadmin that there is data, that leads to a couple follow-up questions:

- Are you successfully executing any other queries on this page? If not, then the most likely culprit is an unsuccessful connection to the db.
- Are you running mysql_connect() before this snippet?

You may also want to refactor this a bit to make sure the query function knows of the appropriate connection and also introduce some error trapping.

```
<?
    // Somewhere towards the beginning of this page/view.
    $db_connection = mysql_connect( $host, $user, $password );
?>

<dt><label for="image">Bild</label></dt>
<select id="image" name="ak_image" value="<?php echo $ak_image; ?>">
<?php 
  // Affirmatively pass the connection to the query. Also, check for errors.
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT bi_pfad, bi_name FROM tbl_bilder ", $db_connection); 
  if( $result )
  {
      $options = ""; 
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $bi_name = $row["bi_name"];
        $bi_pfad = $row["bi_pfad"];
        $options .= "<option value=\"$bi_pfad\">".$bi_name."</option>\n";
      } 
      echo $options;
  }
  else
  {
        // Perform error trapping here.
  } 
  echo "</select>\n";
?>
```

Also, if your version of PHP is new enough to support them, it's probably a good idea for you to switch libraries. At the very minimum I would switch to [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysqli.php) or something that allows for parameterized query setups.